# AuthorizeAttribute and output caching in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm thinking to write custom authorize attribute and I'm not sure about output caching.
Attribute would look like this:

```
 public class AuthorizeWithAreasAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{        
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(Roles))
        {
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(urlHelper.Action(ControllerName, ActionName, new { area = AreaName }));
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

    public string ControllerName { get; set; }

    public string ActionName { get; set; }

    public string AreaName { get; set; }
}
```

I have following quote from book professional asp.net mvc:

> So, what happens if you combine an authorization filter with [OutputCache]? In the worst case, you
>   run the risk of an authorized user first visiting your action, causing it to run and be cached, shortly
>   followed by an unauthorized user, who gets the cached output even though they aren’t authorized.
>   Fortunately, the ASP.NET MVC team has anticipated this problem, and has added special logic to AuthorizeAttribute to make it play well with ASP.NET output caching. It uses a little-known outputcaching
>   API to register itself to run when the output-caching module is about to serve a response from
>   the
>   cache. This prevents unauthorized users from getting cached content.

After reading this, it remains unclear to me - should I do something regarding caching or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you'll be fine. The AuthorizeAttribute will always be used. The output cache may cache the authorized user's content, but it will never display that to an unauthorized user, and vice versa.

Comment: But it may display an authorized user's data to another authorized user!

Comment: Not sure the above is correct according to this?

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/29/asp-net-mvc-tip-40-don-t-cache-pages-that-require-authentication

Comment: @MIP1983 the blog post is wrong (note the reply in the comments there by Phil Haack). The application won't return the cached content to unauthorized users, it will just return the cached content to all authorized requests. Therefore if you had any user-specific personalisation that relied on the outcome of authorization then this would be invalid to use caching. The only (loose) connection between the two concepts is that authorization is generally part of establishing identity and identity may affect what you want the action to return.